# How to dynamically create a database with parameterized queries in node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I want to allow the user to create a database, alongside it's tables through a UI.

I am using node-postgres as my postgresQL driver, alongside nodejs and express.

The code below

```
await db.query('CREATE DATABASE $1', [databaseName]);
```

Does not work, node-postgres throws an error when attempting to parse the dollar sign I guess.

Should I use a concatenated string for this? or is there a way to do it with params?

Comment: Although I am not familiar with postgres, I wanted to know, by any chance did you try out doing ```await db.query(`CREATE DATABASE ${databaseName}`);``` ?

Comment: @Omkar Yes that's what I meant by concatenated string, and it is possible, but I was wondering if it was possible to do with node-postgress's query params

Comment: I found this doc: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries
```{
  text: 'SELECT $1::text as first_name, select $2::text as last_name',
  values: ['Brian', 'Carlson'],
  rowMode: 'array',
}```
What I see here if type of param is string, ```::text``` is specified in the string. I am not sure if this is of any direct help, but I hope it might provide you something to work with.

Comment: @Omkar Sadly that did not work as well.